# How to stub method in mocked object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I need to test code snippet (e.g. from class *UnderTestClass*):

```
def _method_to_test(self)
    ...

    ParsingObject = MyParsingClass()
    if not ParsingObject.parse_string(some_string):
        self.logger.error('Parsing data has failed.')
        return False
    return ParsingObject
```

No matter how I try, can't cover last return statement - *return ParsingObject*, so it have to be something wrong with my mocking of parse_string() method.

I've tried inter alia statements from Python testing tutorial:

```
from my_app import myParsingClass
...

def test_method_to_test_success(self):
    ...

    UnderTestClassMock = Mock(name='UnderTestClass')
    parsePatch = patch('my_app.myParsingClass.MyParsingClass')
    parseMock = parsePatch.start()
    parseInstance = parseMock.return_value

    parseInstance.parse_string.return_value = True             

    res = tested_module.UnderTestClass._method_to_test(UnderTestClassMock)

    parsePatch.stop()

    self.assertIsInstance(res, myParsingClass.MyParsingClass)
```

But unfortunately get only:

> AssertionError: False is not an instance of class 'my_app.myParsingClass.MyParsingClass'

UPDATE: Thanks. I follow your advice, so re-write a bit:

```
    with patch('...') as ParseMock:
             instance = ParseMock.return_value
             ParseMock.parse_string.return_value = True
             res = tested_module.UnderTestClass._method_to_test(UnderTestClassMock)
             assert myParsingClass.MyParsingClass() is instance
             assert myParsingClass.MyParsingClass() is res
```

but still got AssertionError on last line.

EDIT: do I need somehow dependency injection mechanism/framework?

Comment: The name of the test is, lets say, unfortunate. What do you want to test?

Comment: Maybe I overact with these fake names (supposed to be more readable;))
I try to test UnderTestClass._method_to_test(), but you know it already ;)

Comment: Still, I don't get the purpose of your test @user3198088

Comment: I think you should be asserting something like `assert(res is instance)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set return_value on parseMock, not parseInstance:

```
parseMock.parse_string.return_value = True
```

Also you need to stop() the patch after your assert

Comment: Instead of using `patch.start()` and `patch.stop`, consider using the patch as a decorator http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html

Comment: Thanks for answers. 
I'm not sure if patch.stop() should be call after asserts, but I rewrote patching and fix return_value statement, but still got this issue (see my update above). 
What else could I try?

Comment: try with self.assertTrue(isinstance(res, MyParsingClass))

Comment: Strange issue - got TypeError now:
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: I've got now exactly same code as listed below by @geekazoid.
I printed type of MyParsingClass and instance in unit test and it's <class 'mock.MagicMock'> so here looks good.

Comment: No, that's not good. You should patch only the method: patch('my_app.myParsingClass.MyParsingClass.parse_string'). This way you'll get an instance of your class. I didn't understand that you're trying to test a method of the class that your also mocking.

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I didn't check this simplest way at first (I though that it would be too easy to be correct)

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the instance method `parse_string`, not the class method.

```
In [22]: import mock

In [23]: ParseMock = mock.Mock()

In [24]: instance = ParseMock.return_value

In [25]: instance.parse_string.return_value = True

In [26]: parser = ParseMock()

In [27]: parser.parse_string("foo")
Out[27]: True
```

Comment: Thanks. Though still same problem. After change to strictly what you wrote (inside patch of course), I've got: 
AssertionError: False is not an instance of <class 'my_app.myParsingClass.MyParsingClass'>

Comment: I mean, you should not change to strictly what I wrote. The `ParseMock` is an instance of `mock.Mock`.